# How does a Promise.prototype.catch, at the end of a .then chain, receive rejected promises?

Tags: javascript

I know that if a `.then` receives a rejected promise, and it has no handler for it, the *new* promise `.then` returns becomes the state of the promise `.then` received ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)).

In fact, my intuition would tell me this is how `.catch`, appended at the end of a `.then` chain, receives a promise (when all the `.then`s have no rejection handlers). Each `.then` is called, returning duplicates of the original failed promise.

Additionally, when I'm reading this [article](https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling) I get the impression that when a promise's executor *or* a `.then`'s callback simply returns an error object, it'll somehow 'jump' and return this error object to the nearest rejection handler (surely this could be a regular `.then` that has a callback as a second argument or a `.catch()`). Are both ideas right here?

Comment: The only "true" answer here is the one described in _many_ pages of text starting on https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-objects

Comment: The language with which you describe things is quite confusing. *"`.then` receives"*? `.then()` gets executed, and a callback is given it, and that callback gets called with an argument. Do you mean with "`.then` receives" that the callback is called with a certain argument?

Comment: @trincot Sorry, by `.then` 'receiving' a rejected promise I just meant `rejectedPromise.then`

Comment: *"a .then's callback simply returns an error object"*: if it really is returning that, this will fulfil the promise with that object. The article you refer to is actually throwing the Error object, and the essence is in the throwing, not in the Error object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm reading this article I get the impression that it'll somehow 'jump'

No, that's misleading. Your first intuition was right. When the promise that `.then(…)` was called on is rejected, the promise that `.then(…)` returned will also get rejected, and so on down the chain. This even takes some time actually (and other promise handlers might run in between).

Of course, the logical execution flow skips the `then` handlers on all the rejected promise and the next thing from this chain that will run is a `catch` (or `then`) rejection handler, so you might consider it to "jump", but that really an analogy only and is actually implemented by rejecting each promise along the chain.

You get actual jumps of flow control when using promises with `async`/`await` in `try`/`catch` blocks.